# How to redirect to an external link ( url ) no matter the http or https are given or not in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

In Laravel the `Redirect::to` need a full link with `http(s)://`, In Jefrey shortener tutorial he used only full urls to test the app, even The url Validator passes only when given full urls.
Any other methods or other php function to use that redirect to urls without http(s)//  ?

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
Redirect::away('http(s)://')
```

Comment: If i use a famous shortener to redirect to for exemple `tvstream.com` i can see on the adress bar the same link i shortened ! This is the exact result im expecting to have, without the need to add **http(s)://**